# Drop a column in a struct within an Array type

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

My schema looks like this

```
root
 |-- source: string (nullable = true)
 |-- results: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- content: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- ptype: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- domain: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- verb: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- foobar: map (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- key: string
 |    |    |    |-- value: string (valueContainsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- fooId: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- date: string (nullable = false)
 |-- hour: string (nullable = false)
```

I have a df with the above data. I want to create a dataframe **without** `fooId`.
I cannot use `drop` since its a nested column.

The tricky part is `results` is an array and has `content` as a struct.
Inside of which there is  `fooId`

What would be the cleanest way to accomplish this?

Comment: @user6910411 The concept is the same but the structure is different. Here it is a struct with an array.

Comment: Since it's an array, I believe the easiest way would be to use an `UDF` to remove the data. Or you could `explode` the array first but that would change the dataframe structure.

Comment: I would prefer the former approach. So I have to map and then pass it to the udf?Can you elaborate a little more?

Comment: You can create an udf that takes the `results` array as input, then do all necessary processing inside it (i.e. remove `fooId`). You can use `withColumn` to overwrite the `results` column with what the udf returns.